# How to Make Function Execute Formula on Last Row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use the script editor to allow me to execute the function stored in cell A1 every 24 hours. I want the value that is generated to be stored in cell A2, then the next time the script runs I want that value stored in A3, and so it goes. The problem I am having is that I can't get my code to do this.

I have tried editing the last few lines of the script, but I can not get it to work.

```
function recordChanges() {
  var url = 'LINK TO MY SHEET';   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var range = sh.getRange("A1");    
  var values = range.getValues();
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();

  if (values[0][0] != values[1][0]) {
    sh.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
    sh.getRange().setValue(values[0][0]);
  }
}
```

I expect the script to store the value, and the next time it runs I want it to store the value on the cell below the last store valued. Bonus points if you can get it to place the date the new value was generated in the same row but in column B.

Answer (score 0):

getLastRow only returns the last row of the sheet that contains content.

Comment: So how should I change the code to fix the problem? Forgive me, I am brand new to the google-sheets API.

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting your question as "how can I copy the value of A1 to the next empty cell in row 1?"  My apologies if I am misinterpreting your question, please let me know.
It is unclear what you mean by "execute formula on last row"; please clarify and perhaps show the formula. This code does not make A1 change: I am assuming you already have the value of A1 changing somehow, and all you need to do is copy the current value to the end of row one.

```js
function recordChanges() {
  var url = 'LINK TO MY SHEET';   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var range = sh.getRange("A1"); 
  var firstRow = range.getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
  var values = firstRow.getValues();
  values[0].push(values[0][0]);
  sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, firstRow.getLastColumn() + 1).setValues(values);
}
```